# Alternatives to fittest-win and Moran processes as simple mathematical models of selection

Tags: evolution, natural-selection, mathematical-models, theoretical-biology

When modeling [selective sweeps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selective_sweep) as a micro-building block in models of [macroevolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macroevolution) (not to be confused with misuses of this in creationist arguments), I use the fittest-win model of selection as a first approximation, or [Moran process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moran_process) model when I want a more reasonable approximation.

In the fittest win model the probability for a mutant of fitness r to invade a host population of fitness 1 is 100% if r > 1 and 0 otherwise. In the Moran process model, the mutant of fitness r invades with probability $\frac{1 - r^{-1}}{1 - r^{-n}}$ for a finite population. Alternative in the limit as n goes to infinite, a mutant with r > 1 invades with probability $1 - \frac{1}{r}$ and 0 otherwise.

In general I am interested in simple models of selection of a single (or small concentration of) mutant invading an asexual host population of fitness 1 (with fitness constant and independent of frequency). **Are there other common mathematical models for selection of this type?**

Answer (score 1):

I may suggest to give a look to game theory based model and their generalization from homogenous spatial diatribution to network like model. An easy review can be found in Martin A. Nowak's *Evolutionary Dynamics* (Harvard press 2006).

In particular you can see the classical Moran process as an evolutionary graph game going on a complete graph with identical weights. Changing the topology of the graph can give different results, though it is not necessary (and there're results showing in which case a graph behave just as a Moran process).

Graph related behaviour are, i.e., suppressing or amplifier of selection...